# Jquery to find and replace script line in header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I have a script src for a deprecated version of JQuery which I cannot control (controlled externally via a CMS, not cross-domain, just no access to changing it) and I'd like to change the script src to a newer version of Jquery.

Old code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

Replace with:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: once it's loaded, it's loaded, changing the src attribute doesn't remove the script.

Comment: You want jQuery to find and replace a reference to jQuery. jQuery will already be loaded - how does this help?

Comment: Damn, thought I could, didn't think about the loading aspect :/ thanks

Comment: @adeneo: please add your answer so I can accept it. Apologies for my backwards thinking today.

Comment: I don't think there's a good reason to downvote this question. As other commenters have said it's not possible / wouldn't work but still it's a question I had never considered.

Comment: It's possible to load multiple versions of jQuery in noConflict mode: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ but the 2nd loaded jQuery version won't change $() or jQuery. You would need to make a special reference such as jQueryNewer = jQuery.noConflict(); then use jQueryNewer() instead of jQuery() or $()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once an external script has loaded, it can't be removed as it's already loaded into memory, so changing the source would just load another version of jQuery without removing the first version, so you'd have two versions of jQuery, creating a conflict, and in many cases nothing will work.

There is a workaround if you absolutely have to:

```
$(function() {
    $j_142 = $.noConflict(true);
    $j_142.getScript('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js', function() {
        $j_191 = $.noConflict(true);

    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NgrDN/1/)

now you have two versions of jQuery mapped, and to use them you'd do:

```
$j_191('#selector')
```

of course, this would cause issues with code already written, but you could probably get away with just mapping the second script to a new variable or something ?

**EDIT:**

You could use a closure to map one of those values back to the dollarsign within the closure:

```
(function($) { //anonymous self invoking function

    // now you could use the dollarsign as normal

    $(function() {  // document ready function

    });

})($j_191);
```

Comment: thanks. So how would I use `$j_191` around entire blocks of code rather than changing each selector? There's quite a few..

Comment: Thanks, What about a `document.ready` example please? :) thanks

Comment: If you're using getScript to get the script, the document is already ready, you just need to wrap it in the anonymous function ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var oldJquery = document.querySelectorAll('script[src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"]');
oldJquery.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"
```

Once you do this, it will automotically will download coz it is live dom element. All changes should be reflected immediately.

But I would suggest that long term this is not good idea. what if CDN from google is down.

You might be in trouble. Just take precaution while doing this changes.

Answer (score 0):

That easy, this is your code:

```
$("script[src='js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js']").attr('src', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.2/jquery.min.js');
```

This is example http://jsfiddle.net/rebeen/KwLM3/